# How to Get Most Recent Data in a power BI Report with less delay

Tags: powerbi, report, refresh

I have 3 tables Table1, Table2,Table3 which are populated by 3 jobs.
a) Table1 Refreshed in every 5 minute
b) Table2 Refreshed instantly
c) Table3 Refreshed Monthly as it is monthly prediction data

There is an view which is using Table1,Table2,Table3 and and have around 50 calculated columns. This view is using by a power BI report.

How do I design a solution that the power BI report will get the most updated data. If we execute the view than it will slow down as table1 and Table2 data changes also these tables contains millions of records.

Can any body suggest a good solution.All are in sql server database.

Answer (score 0):

Create your reports in Direct Query mode since all the data are in SQL database it is supported by Power BI. Use this for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery). What this does is once you flited the data all the data would be that is on the tables.